# Server installer says 'continue without network' instead of 'continue' at network config part. It shows my three ethernet ports

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

DHCP seems to work fine because one of the adapters listed has an IP right away, but the continuation button never changes to just 'continue'. 20.04.1.

Comment: Yea, but when I try selecting e.g. the one with the assigned IP, it just opens a menu, and I hit something like auto-config IPv4, and then it just 'reloads' the IP, and the 'continue without network' just stays.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04.1 but the problem was that I was simply plugging the ethernet cable into the wrong port. It works fine now on the Debian I'd installed before. Should I delete this whole post?

Comment: Damn this is my exact issue, except I only have 1 ethernet port!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the ethernet cable was plugged into the wrong port.